# rails STI subclass returns superclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sti

I have a STI class hierarchy like so:

```
Producer, Partner, Freelancer < Statusowner < Contact
```

When I call e.g. `Partner.all` I see rails producing this:

```
SELECT "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."type" IN ('Partner', 'Producer', 'Partner', 'Freelancer') ORDER BY contacts.name
```

You see that it first includes Partner, and then all Subclasses of Statusowner, including Partner again. This happens similarly with all subclasses.

I have set `self.descentants` in Statusowner, so everything gets loaded early in the development environment:

```
class Statusowner < User
  def self.descendants
    [Producer, Sales, Partner, Freelancer]
  end
end
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

probably you simply should not redefine descendants method. 
maybe if you just require the files after defining the class would be enough.

if you prefer a kind of a hack to autoload maybe you could change your code to:

```
class Statusowner < User
  MY_DESCENDANTS = [Producer, Sales, Partner, Freelancer]
end
```

I believe this could make you achieve the same result but this way you don't override the original method. Oh, by the way, the subclasses are  inheriting the overroden method, so all these subclasses have the method descendants returning `[Producer, Sales, Partner, Freelancer]`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Will try ASAP.